# XCode - ld: library not found for -lfile_vacuum

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

I added a CocoaPod (`SwiftySandboxFileAccess`) to my project and now I'm getting the following error:

```
Ld /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Products/Debug/FileVacuum.app/Contents/MacOS/FileVacuum normal x86_64 (in target 'FileVacuum' from project 'FileVacuum')
    cd /Users/mike/Documents/Mikeumus/code/FileVacuum/menubar-filevacuum
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-macos10.15 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Products/Debug -L. -LCarthage -LFileVacuum -LFileVacuum.xcworkspace -LFileVacuumLauncher2 -LFileVacuumTests -LFileVacuumUITests -LMenubar-FileVacuumTests -LMenubar-FileVacuumUITests -LPods -LCarthage/Build -LCarthage/Checkouts -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum\ 2020-06-08\ 11-57-59 -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive -LFileVacuum/Pods -LFileVacuum.xcworkspace/xcshareddata -LFileVacuum.xcworkspace/xcuserdata -LPods/Headers -LPods/Local\ Podspecs -LPods/SwiftySandboxFileAccess -LPods/Target\ Support\ Files -LCarthage/Build/Mac -LCarthage/Build/iOS -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/SwiftSupport -LFileVacuum/Pods/Headers -LFileVacuum/Pods/Local\ Podspecs -LFileVacuum/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files -LFileVacuum.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm -LFileVacuum.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/mike.xcuserdatad -LPods/Headers/Public -LPods/SwiftySandboxFileAccess/SwiftySandboxFileAccess -LPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-FileVacuum -LPods/Target\ Support\ Files/SwiftySandboxFileAccess -LCarthage/Build/Mac/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM -LCarthage/Build/iOS/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/SwiftSupport/macosx -LPods/Headers/Public/SwiftySandboxFileAccess -LPods/SwiftySandboxFileAccess/SwiftySandboxFileAccess/Classes -LCarthage/Build/Mac/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM/Contents -LCarthage/Build/iOS/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM/Contents -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Demo\ iOS -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Demo\ macOS -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ Shared -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ iOS -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ macOS -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications/FileVacuum.app -LCarthage/Build/Mac/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources -LCarthage/Build/iOS/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/Supporting\ Files -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ Shared/Test\ Assets -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ Shared/Tools -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications/FileVacuum.app/Contents -LCarthage/Build/Mac/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF -LCarthage/Build/iOS/AppReceiptValidator.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL/include-ios -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL/include-macos -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL/lib-ios -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL/lib-macos -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/Supporting\ Files/iOS -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/Supporting\ Files/macOS -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ Shared/Test\ Assets/Other\ Receipts -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications/FileVacuum.app/Contents/Frameworks -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications/FileVacuum.app/Contents/MacOS -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications/FileVacuum.app/Contents/Resources -LFileVacuum/FileVacuum.xcarchive/Products/Applications/FileVacuum.app/Contents/_CodeSignature -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL/include-ios/openssl -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/OpenSSL/include-macos/openssl -LCarthage/Checkouts/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator/AppReceiptValidator\ Tests\ Shared/Test\ Assets/Other\ Receipts/unparseable -L/Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Products/Debug/SwiftySandboxFileAccess -F/Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/mike/Documents/Mikeumus/code/FileVacuum/menubar-filevacuum/Carthage/Build/Mac -filelist /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FileVacuum.build/Debug/FileVacuum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FileVacuum.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FileVacuum.build/Debug/FileVacuum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FileVacuum_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-instr-generate -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FileVacuum.build/Debug/FileVacuum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FileVacuum.swiftmodule -ObjC -lSwiftySandboxFileAccess -framework AppReceiptValidator -framework Automator -lfile_vacuum -lresolv -lPods-FileVacuum -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FileVacuum.build/Debug/FileVacuum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FileVacuum_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Products/Debug/FileVacuum.app/Contents/MacOS/FileVacuum -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FileVacuum-defywbakdmgzprcegfjrlcpktbta/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftyStoreKit.build/Debug/SwiftyStoreKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftyStoreKit.swiftmodule

ld: library not found for -lfile_vacuum
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

`pod install` and `pod update` ***was*** giving the following warnings:

```
[!] The `FileVacuum [Debug]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-FileVacuum/Pods-FileVacuum.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `FileVacuum [Release]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-FileVacuum/Pods-FileVacuum.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I changed the "Target" level `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` to `$(inherited)` and these warnings went away but I changed the "Project" level `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` and don't remember what it was before I changed it so I just set it to `$(inherited), $(PROJECT_DIR) recursive`

---

I have done the following:

- Close the Xcode;
- Run pod install and pod update;
- Open the new .xcworkspace;
- Clean and Build Project;

---

Here's some of app's settings:

[image]

`LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH` setting is the same for the "Project" and "Target" levels:
[image]

---

"file_vacuum" doesn't result in a file/settings search:

[image]

In the screenshot above this one you can see I'm linking a `libfile_vacuum.a`, I don't know if this is the same `file_vacuum` causing the issue.

---

`Podfile`

```
platform :macos, '10.15'

target 'FileVacuum' do
  pod 'SwiftySandboxFileAccess', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is failing to locate `file_vacuum` library which is a static library based on your screenshots. Make sure you add the path for that file in your `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH` in your target Build Settings. You can also just search for search paths and find it there. In general, whenever there's an error about not finding a header file or an object, it's related to search paths and means Compiler isn't able to find information for that type / library.

Framework, Library, and Header search paths are the three types you can define and help the Compiler to find those files.